# TreeView setOnEditCommit trouble

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, treeview, cell

I've got some problems with setOnEditCommit TreeView method.
So here's my code

```
public class MyCheckBoxTreeViewConsulter extends TreeView {

public MyCheckBoxTreeViewConsulter() {
    super();
    this.setEditable(true);

    this.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<ChampBdd>forTreeView());

        this.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            System.out.println("hi");
        });
}}
```

I have a result like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uneri.jpg

Whenever I double click on one of theses row, nothing happens.

I want this kind of result to edit data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWSz1.jpg

Any thoughts on this ?

Feel free to ask more of my code if you need it.

Comment: Surely you want a `TextFieldTreeCell`?

Comment: I'll lose checkbox ?

Comment: If you need both a check box *and* a text field, you need to implement your own cell.

Comment: Furthermore `CheckBoxTreeCell` does not trigger `onEditCommit` since every cell is always in "editing mode".

Comment: Do you have a track on how to do that ? It would be nice

Comment: unrelated; don't extend a control (or any other class) if you can reach the same by configuration

Comment: maybe related:: TreeView doesn't fully respect commitHandlers - known bugs https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187309 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187473

Comment: and last for today ;) please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly